# c# VS2012 how to use .mdf db script to create database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have `Magazine.mdf` database file created in SQL Server 2012 and program created in VS2012.

What is good way to create this base on user system?

I can use script of database?

If yes how to auto install libaries for SQL Server `.mdf` database with my program and run this script?

Target user needs a program that will install on his system, and the first time run create the database.

I'm standing in front of wall. Thanks for help!

Comment: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: If you want to use an `.mdf` database - there **must be** a copy of SQL Server - either on each machine that uses your application, or centrally on some server that all machines can access. No way around this. You can install the free SQL Server **Express** edition on each machine (and you get up to 10 GB of database size) - or you can connect the machines to a common database **server** that runs SQL Server.

Comment: To create the database, you can either use Management Studio and use `Tasks > Generate Scripts` from the Object Explorer. This will create a `.sql` script for creating the database objects (and optionally also insert data into them, e.g. for lookup tables)

Comment: I understand, client must buy own copy of SQL server 2012 install it and then they can install may software. Which will create base Magazine.mdf from script.
I understand SQL server is not solution for software of invoices and magazine. Sold massively to small businesses discs cd / dvd. Programs that use SQL server need to implement.

Comment: Msi installer can install SQL server Express instance on user computer automatically?